# Difference between plugin and external jar file

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin

In the context of java, is tehre any difference conceptually between 'plugin' and 'external jar/third party library/ external dependency etc?

A corollary to the question is: When in eclipse you download and 'install' a plugin, does it do anything else except copy a jar in the .plugin directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Eclipse plugin must contain a number of entries in the `MANIFEST.MF` to be recognized as a plugin. These give the name and version of the plugin along with lists of other plugins that are required and numerous other values.

The plugin may also contain a `plugin.xml` which defines the Eclipse extension points the plugin uses and may also declare new extension points.

Eclipse plugins do not have to be jar files, the equivalent directory structure is also acceptable.

When Eclipse installs a plugin it takes information from the MANIFEST.MF and plugin.xml to update internal tables of things like extension point contributions, class paths for the each plugin and so on.

Example plugin.xml which declares a new extension point and uses an existing one:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension-point id="editor" name="%extension-point.name" schema="schema/editor.exsd"/>
   <extension
         id="coreFragment"
         point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
      <fragment
            uri="fragment.e4xmi">
      </fragment>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Example MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: greg.music.core.common,greg.music.core.e4util,greg.mus
 ic.core.editor,greg.music.core.preferences,greg.music.core.progress,g
 reg.music.core.services,greg.music.core.showin,greg.music.core.util,g
 reg.music.core.views,greg.music.core.xml
Service-Component: OSGI-INF/playerStateService.xml,OSGI-INF/preference
 Settings.xml,OSGI-INF/extensionFactory.xml
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-Name: %Bundle-Name
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,greg.music.forms;bundle-versi
 on="1.0.0",greg.music.parts;bundle-version="1.0.0",greg.music.annotat
 ions;bundle-version="1.0.0",javazoom.jlgui.basicplayer;bundle-version
 ="1.6.0",org.eclipse.jface;bundle-version="3.8.101",org.eclipse.e4.co
 re.contexts;bundle-version="1.1.0",org.eclipse.e4.core.commands;bundl
 e-version="0.10.1",org.eclipse.e4.core.di;bundle-version="1.1.0",org.
 eclipse.e4.core.services;bundle-version="1.0.0",org.eclipse.e4.ui.mod
 el.workbench;bundle-version="0.10.1",org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench;bund
 le-version="0.11.0",org.eclipse.e4.ui.services;bundle-version="0.10.3
 ",com.ibm.icu;bundle-version="4.4.2",org.eclipse.emf.common;bundle-ve
 rsion="2.9.0",org.eclipse.emf.ecore;bundle-version="2.9.0",org.eclips
 e.e4.ui.css.swt.theme;bundle-version="0.9.100",org.eclipse.e4.ui.di;b
 undle-version="1.0.0",org.joda.time;bundle-version="2.3.0",com.google
 .guava;bundle-version="14.0.1"
Bundle-Vendor: %Bundle-Vendor
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.201310241930
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Activator: greg.music.core.Activator
Import-Package: javax.annotation;version="1.0.0",javax.inject;version=
 "1.0.0"
Bundle-SymbolicName: greg.music.core;singleton:=true
```

Comment: So if i wish to write an eclipse plugin, I would need to provide manifest.mf? or is there a tool to generate the manifest.mf if i provide some specific paramters?

Comment: In Eclipse there is a New / Project / Plug-in Project menu item that will generate the basic plugin including the manifest.mf. There is an editor for the manifest and plugin.xml that makes it easier to manage the contents.