# Difference between Jar and Plugin in Java and when to use them

Tags: java, maven, plugins, jar

What is the difference between Jar and Plugin in Java? Both looks the same by achieving the same purpose and when do use Jar and when do we use Plugin.

Comment: Refer To this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/19576567/7865621  it will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A plugin is an extension to Maven, something used to produce your artifact. Plugins are used only to make maven process successful. They are not directly connected to your application. plugins do not include in your last `war`/`jar` file for the service or client.

A dependency is a library that is needed by the application you are building, at compile and/or test and/or runtime time. the classes you used from jars will include in your final `war`/`jar`.

This will be helpful for you,

[What is the difference in maven between dependency and plugin tags in pom xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881663/what-is-the-difference-in-maven-between-dependency-and-plugin-tags-in-pom-xml)

[Difference between plugin and external jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19575194/difference-between-plugin-and-external-jar-file)

Answer (score 0):

plug-in is a software component that adds a specific feature to any computer program.It specially use to customize any computer program.But .jar file is a java executable file which can only run on an environment which Java installed.